# Android Studio Path (ANDROID-HOME) not able to set?

Tags: android, path, android-studio

I am facing the below problem while importing the downloaded project into Andoroid Stuio. 
Please help me.

**

```
Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.7-bin.zip'.
Build file '/Users/Rajesh.K/Desktop/Test/Project/build.gradle' line: 9
A problem occurred evaluating project ':Project'.
A problem occurred evaluating project ':Project'.
SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
```

**

Please help me to come out of this isssue. I am facing this issue in the Android Studio Mac version.

Comment: What do you mean by "importing the downloaded project form Andoroid Stuio"? Put more details

Comment: @PareshMayani Please now look .. i am trying to import the project which i have downloaded from github,

Comment: @itsrajesh4uguys After I exported the Gradle configuration via Eclipse I missed to add the `settings.gradle` file to the project folder. After the error message disappeared.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Are you trying to imort `studio` project into `Android studio` or `eclipse` project into `Android studio`.?

Try to set up your `ANDROID_HOME` as studio asking you. ( `export ANDROID_HOME="PATh to your SDK folder"` )   and run studio form this console.

Or you can try to configure in within `Android Studio` (`File->Project Structure->Android SDK`) And then you should set the proper `SDK` path.

Comment: not working in as 0.4.6; neither setting it in local.properties, or exporting the path as ANDROID_HOME is solving this problem

Answer (score 0):

I faced something similar but the difference was I had already set the variable into `Android Studio` and even with that, it was not recognized.

What I did was a simple `File -> Invalidade Cache and Restart -> Invalidade and Restart`.

I did not go deeper to check if it is a known issue on `Android Studio`.

Comment: This did not help