# error running build target module is undefined

Tags: android, android-studio

I have just installed Android Studio and when I'm trying to build I get this message:

```
error running build   
target module is undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click Help -> Check For Update

Answer (score 2):

- Go Run -> Edit Configurations...
- Check Android Application (on the left)
- Select your project
- In the General tab slect a module (your app)

That worked for me

Comment: My project doesn't show up in the modules combobox. What could the reason for this be?

Comment: Even though the app was already selected this still worked. Very very weird.

Answer (score 2):

Today I had the same problem, these steps worked for me:

- Close Android Studio
- Edit local.properties in project folder, set sdk.dir path to the original android-sdk path which eclipse uses (ie. sdk.dir=c:\Users\Foo\android-sdks)
- Load project again, a dialog appears which asks if you really want to use the other path, click yes. if it still does not work, then
- Close Android Studio again
- Edit local.properties again and set the path back to the original path
- Load the project again, the dialog appears again, select yes

My project has been loaded correctly now, maybe it will also work for others, weird problem ;-)

Comment: You suggestion actually worked for me. I only had to change path in local.properties once and then I could start it again. Thank you for taking your time to share it.

Comment: This works very well for me too! I've noticed that this error ocurred when I tried to checkout a project on another pc... some files must not have to be versionated... (iml files). Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

In `Android Studio` Edit Configuration section look for `Android Application`. Then in the module select your app name. By default if project is imported this will be `DEFAULT`. Change this with your app name rebuild the app with `gradle build` and everything else will be good to go. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the gradlew.bat file. This file will try to build your project. When the execution fail will prompt you the version of building tools your sdk miss. Install this version and your project will build.

gradlew.bat calls the environmental variable ANDROID_HOME which has to have as value the path of the android sdk, See from more information,
[Android Studio Path (ANDROID-HOME) not able to set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19375098/android-studio-path-android-home-not-able-to-set)